In MySQL is it redundant to include id as the last field in a composite index?
Knowing id is the primary key...
Lets say we have an index in MySQL like
 account_id / assignee_id / is_public

but the sorting of a query that needs this index is by id (the primary index)
changing the index to
account_id / assignee_id / is_public / id 

is easier on the DB.  Correct or incorrect?
If so where do you see that in the docs?

The query has  account_id, assignee_id, is_public in the WHERE clause, then ordering by id. But the column to the sort is id is the primary key in the DB and hence does MySQL by default keep the primary key in order.

Index choices must be made to support specific queries. Can you please show an example query you are trying to optimize?
(I did not downvote)

Are you using account_id, assignee_id, is_public in the WHERE clause, then ordering by id? In this case, I think the modified index should indeed help.

I don't know if this is documented, but https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/mysql-indexes.html is where it would be if so.

By the way, when I requested you to show an example query, I meant show a specific query in SQL. Vaguely describing some of the terms of a WHERE clause may get you similarly vague answers. In general, when asking questions about code problems, you should show your code.

Correct or incorrect? If the index is covering and all conditions in WHERE are column=value then correct else (imho) incorrect. See execution plan.

A query with a WHERE clause like this:
...
WHERE account_id=? AND assignee_id=? AND is_public=?
ORDER BY id

Would benefit from an index defined on columns (account_id, assignee_id, is_public, id).
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/innodb-index-types.html says:

In InnoDB, each record in a secondary index contains the primary key columns for the row, as well as the columns specified for the secondary index.

If you define the table using the InnoDB storage engine (which has been the default storage engine in MySQL for years), then the primary key column is implicitly appended to the index. So an index on (account_id, assignee_id, is_public) is actually an index on (account_id, assignee_id, is_public, id) without you specifying it.
This is not necessarily true if you use a different storage engine (you should have a very good reason for doing so).
If any of the conditions in the WHERE clause are not using =, then the rules change. That is, if you use any inequality or range comparisons, then the sorting-by-primary-key optimization of the index doesn't work, and MySQL has to sort the result manually.
Read more about how MySQL optimizes ORDER BY here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/order-by-optimization.html
You should use EXPLAIN to analyze how MySQL plans to use indexes for your query.
You might like my presentation How to Design Indexes, Really, or the video of me presenting it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU
